# Fetch ClaimType Enumerations via REST

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

We're happily enriching our claims via custom RESTful API, but is it possible to instead display the fetched claim values (comma delimetered, for example) in a drop-down and ask used to pick one?

```xml
<ClaimType Id="city">
  <DisplayName>city where you work</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
  <Restriction>
      <!-- FETCH THESE VIA REST --> 
      <Enumeration Text="Bellevue" Value="bellevue" SelectByDefault="false" />
  </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Turned out it wasn't possible in B2C.