# Azure AD B2C - Autofill known user data at signup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to know if its possible to make the SignUp Form to programmatically query some service (maybe a rest API or whatever), and then suggest some of the retrieved data to the user by filling it automatically in the fields.

Comment: With custom policies, you can [call rest endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom).  I don't think you can achieve what you're looking for though.

Comment: Are saying: "as the form changes, I want to retreive data from a rest endpoint and display it to the user"?

Comment: @spottedmahn not necessarily as the form changes, doing it once when the user is presented with the SignUp form is enough. Thanks for the link, that should cover the "get the data part", but not the "fill the fields" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the number of answers on my [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253190/fetch-claimtype-enumerations-via-rest), I'm assuming the answer is no. As part of your UserJourney, you can make REST calls, which can eventually return you claims, but you cannot do anything with those claims when it comes to UI.

[UI customizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) look promising, but disallow JavaScript so you cannot "hack" your preselected values in either.